# emitted signal is not caught in derived class

Tags: qt, signals

```
class Settings : public  QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Settings();
    ~Settings();
    void setValue(QString key, QVariant value);

// [...]
signals:
    void settingsChanged();
// [...]


class ApplicationSettings : public Settings
{
public:
    explicit ApplicationSettings();
    ~ApplicationSettings();

public slots:
    void save();
// [...]
```

Every time I change a value via `setvalue(...)`in the base class,
I do `emit settingsChanged()`.

In the constructor of `ApplicationSettings` I say:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(settingsChanged()), this, SLOT(save()));
```

But `save()` is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've been writing this question I noticed that I did not include `Q_OBJECT` in my derived class. Adding this, the signal was connected correctly. I think this question may still be useful for others, because it was also new for me that the `Q_OBJECT`-macro of the base class is not "inherited".